# Why using Sql parameters are not supported?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parameters

If I use the parameters to set the value in order to update the fields, nothing has been updated, but if I assign the value to the field directly, everything works fine.
Here is my sql script with parameters that won't work:

```
DECLARE @ItemValue  NUMERIC(2,1) = 0.0,
@ItemName   NVARCHAR = NULL,
@RuleID     INT,
@IsValid    BIT

SET @ItemValue  =9
SET @ItemName = 'chbWorkingTimePerDay'
SET @RuleID     = 1
SET @IsValid    = 1

UPDATE hrms.RuleValue  

SET ItemValue   = @ItemValue,
    IsValid     = @IsValid

FROM hrms.RuleItem RI

JOIN hrms.RuleValue RV 
ON RI.RuleItemID = RV.RuleItemID

WHERE RI.ItemName =  @ItemName
        AND RV.RuleID = @RuleID
```

Here is my sql script without parameters that works:

```
UPDATE hrms.RuleValue  

SET ItemValue   = 8.0,
    IsValid     = 1

FROM hrms.RuleItem RI

JOIN hrms.RuleValue RV 
ON RI.RuleItemID = RV.RuleItemID

WHERE RI.ItemName =  'chbWorkingTimePerDay'
        AND RV.RuleID = 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@ItemName NVARCHAR = NULL` will translate to `@ItemName NVARCHAR(1) = NULL`, which will cut off the string. You need to set `NVARCHAR` size.

So use:

```
@ItemName   NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
```

instead of:

```
@ItemName   NVARCHAR= NULL
```

SqlFiddle is available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a1fa96aff51b6248c0c1181177d61c64).

Comment: Thanks, that shortens my code, but it could not help me to solve the problem, and yes not RI but RV.

Comment: It works. Thanks for the instant answer and your time. @d-shih